# Why is the while loop in my program running to infinity

Tags: python

My python program is supposed to be a mock craigslist forum post that reads a text file that has a bunch of inputs.The main code looks like that

```
filename = input()
myFile = open(filename, "r")
mssgBoard = [["bicycle"], ["microwave"], ["dresser"], ["truck"],["chicken"]]
choice = ""
while (choice != "4"):
    print ("1. Insert an item.")
    print ("2. Search an item.")
    print ("3. Print the message board.")
    print ("4. Quit.")
    choice = myFile.readline()
    if (choice == "1"):
        userInput = ""
        userInput1 = 0
        print ("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c: ")
        userInput = myFile.readline()
        print ("Enter the item cost: ")
        userInput1 = myFile.readline()
        if userInput == "b":
            mssgBoard[0].append(userInput1)
        elif userInput == "m":
            mssgBoard[1].append(userInput1)
        elif userInput == "d":
            mssgBoard[2].append(userInput1)
        elif userInput == "t":
            mssgBoard[3].append(userInput1)
        elif userInput == "c":
            mssgBoard[4].append(userInput1)
```

and the inputs are

```
1
b
50
1
m
30
3
2
m
40
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't striping the newline characters from the inputs you are reading from the file.  Each of the lines has a hidden `\n` at the end of them.  It is a simple fix to just add `.strip()`

```
choice = myFile.readline().strip()
```